# How to install Emgu CV wrapper?

Tags: c#, wrapper, emgucv

I found a simillar question but the answer didn´t help me!
SO I´m trying to install Emgu CV wrapper. I´m following the steps presentes on the website.
Unfortunatelly I´m not able to build the examples...It gives me build failed...
Maybe I´m missing something . I´m using visual studio 2088 and windows xp.

Comment: Surely it says something more than "build failed?"  Look in the Output window.

Comment: Sounds like your version of Visual Studio just too advanced. Try one from this decade.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is you haven't reference the EMGU.CV, Emgu.CV.UI and EMGU.Util files again. When you open the project look in the 'Solution Explorer' panel. Expand the folder References. You should have three references for EMGU.CV, Emgu.CV.UI and EMGU.Util these may have yellow error symbols next to them. The key is you must delete the references. Making note of there names if there are more then these three.

Then Right click on the References folder and select "Add Reference" you will have to wait for windows to build the references up depending on your machine. In the tabs at the top of the Add References window select Browse.

Locate the folder where you installed EMGU (I keep the folder in my Visual Studio 2008 folder for ease since you have to do this for every project you make) in the 'bin' folder locate the references EMGU.CV.dll, Emgu.CV.UI.dll and EMGU.Util.dll and add them
[EDIT] I have written an article to help others install EMGU please take a look if you need help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you add reference for those?? If you don't follow Chris's by adding it.

If you are meeting the problem "'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception." 
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation 
look at section 1.4